# How to add action to map area in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I have a img that has a clikable map in template.

I want to add Ember.js action to this map. So i did it like this:

```
<map name="tabsy">
        <area coords="0,0, 32,432" {{action 'mainpage.subpage1'}} />
        <area coords="432,0, 432,432" {{action 'mainpage.subpage2'}} />
        <area coords="432,0, 432,432" {{action 'mainpage.subpage3'}} />
      </map>
```

But this is not working. Pointer cursor is gone from the image and no action is taken when i click it.

So how to instruct Ember.js to load mainpage.subpage1 template when i click on a map area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `action` to work as `linkTo` e.g. transition to a route, say `mainpage.subpage1` you could implement an event handler in the controller that is backing up the view representing your map.

For example:

```
App.MapController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  goTo: function(route) {
    this.transitionTo(route);
  }
});
```

And use it like this:

```
{{action goTo 'mainpage.subpage1'}}
```

See [here](http://jsbin.com/amitik/3/edit) for a simple example.